# No overload for method 'X' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#

I'm facing a problem in C# right now which is bugging me a lot..
Anyway here is a part of the code;

```
public class blocked
{
   public static void blockedOpcodes()
   {
    Dictionary<ushort, String> Opcodes
    = new Dictionary<ushort, String>();
            Opcodes.Add(0x2005, "Blocked: TD46 Tool");
    }
}
```

Continue, I'm trying to get the list of the opcodes from dictionary;

```
 if (Project_name.blocked.blockedOpcodes(current.Opcode))
{
}
```

^ but that one shows error 'No overload for method 'blockedOpcodes' takes 1 arguments.'

EDIT1: I tried to change

```
   public static void blockedOpcodes()
   {
```

to

```
   public static void blockedOpcodes(ushort opcode)
   {
```

But another error shows up with 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool''

PS: I'm completely beginner! I have only started a week ago.

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: You say *'I'm trying to get the list of opcodes from the dictionary'*, but your code implies you're actually trying to find out if the current opcode is *in* the dictionary.  Which is it?

Comment: You're right ye, what I want is a list so when the opcode is found out = disconnect connection and write a message in the console

Comment: So why do you need a list?  Anton's answer below shows you how to check if the code is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what exactly are your trying to achieve.
If you're trying to find out if the `current.Ocpode` is in your dictionary, that you might want to change your code like this:

```
public class blocked
{
   public static Dictionary<ushort, String> blockedOpcodes()
   {
    Dictionary<ushort, String> Opcodes
    = new Dictionary<ushort, String>();
            Opcodes.Add(0x2005, "Blocked: TD46 Tool");
    }
}
```

Now you have a method which returns you a dictionary with opcodes.

```
if (Project_name.blocked.blockedOpcodes().ContainsKey(current.Opcode))
{
    //current.Opcode is in the Dictionary
    //do what you wanted 
    string text = Project_name.blocked.blockedOpcodes()[current.Opcode];
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Some useful links for you:

- [Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)
- [Interactive playground](http://www.learncs.org/en/Dictionaries)

**upd**

```
public static bool isOpcodeAllowed(ushort opcode) 
{ 
    //if opcode is 0x2005 and in Opcodes there is a key 0x2005 
    //then the next line will return true
    if (Opcodes.ContainsKey(opcode)) 
    { 
           string text = Opcodes[opcode];
           //there is a string "Blocked: TD46 Tool" in the text variable 
           Console.WriteLine(text); //what do you see here?
           Log1.LogMsg(text); 
           return false; 
     }
     return true; 
 }
```

**Upd2**

**This is not an example!** This is an explanation why you're code doesn't work!
What do you think is going on here:
    Opcodes.ContainsValue(Opcodes.ContainsKey(opcode)));

First you'll get the value of this expression:

```
Opcodes.ContainsKey(opcode)
```

And the value [is true or false.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then you do  `Opcodes.ContainsValue(true);`
the result is false, because you don't have value 'true' in your dictionary, you have *strings* there!

**upd4**

How to use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<ushort, string> dict = new Dictionary<ushort, string>();
```

now you have a dict, it's empty.

```
dict.Add(0x2005, "Blocked: TD46 Tool");
```

now you have one record in it. The record has Key and Value.

Value is "Blocked: TD46 Tool" and that's a `string`!

Key is 0x2005 and that's a `ushort`.

`dict.ContaintsKey(0x2005)` - returns `true`. Because you have a key 0x2005 in your dict.

`dict.ContaintsKey(0x105)` - returns `false`. Because you don't have a key 0x105 in your dictionary.

`dict[0x2005]` - returns "Blocked: TD46 Tool" because this is a Value or the record with Key.

if you do this:

```
string text = dict[0x2005];
```

you'll get "Blocked: TD46 Tool" stored in the `text` variable.

Now you can send the `text` to the log, console whatever.

If you press "play" here https://dotnetfiddle.net/XEhhst
you'll see that the code works.

Comment: I did it. but using another way, would you mind posting a working code to get the msg of the opcode?   
        public static bool isOpcodeAllowed(ushort opcode)
        {            
                if (Opcodes.ContainsKey(opcode))
                {
                    Log1.LogMsg(X?X?);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
        }

Comment: no it doesn't. probably something like;                     string txt = blockedOpcodes.ContainsValue[opcode]; <- probably something like this will work but I can't get it to work

Comment: @Skipper see the update. and please read the article about Dictionary. It's very simple.

Comment: I took a look at it and I didn't find what I wanted.. I want something like;                         Log1.LogMsg(Opcodes.ContainsValue(Opcodes.ContainsKey(opcode))); but of course dat doesn't work.. so that one shows up the value 'string' if the opcode like containskey or that's what i understood xD

Comment: ContainsValue doesn't give you the value, it gives you the answer Yes or No (true or false). Did you try the code from the update? What do you get there?

Comment: Ye I tried it and it didn't do anything. look here in dat:                     Opcodes.Add(0x2005, "Blocked: TD46 Tool X 2005"); I want to show the text "Blocked: etc" >> and i think that's the value

Comment: LoL, what do you mean it didn't do anything? Do you know how to use debugger? What happens when you run the code? Because I'm sure it *is doing* something. What it does: it checks if there is an opcode in the dictionary. And if it's there it will read the string "Blocked" and send it to the Log1. Is it what you want?

Comment: Do I look like a REAL noob to you?.. And ye the code didn't work, its like it didn't even put the text or anything else. look; http://i.imgur.com/Za8xaxU.png
Anyway could u please just please do the thing I told you up? like Log1.LogMsg(Opcodes.ContainsValue(Opcodes.ContainsKey(opcode))); cause I'm sure 10000% that its the one which shows the text

Comment: So your code is failing because Socket is disposed. It has nothing to do with dictionary.

Comment: Just in case u don't believe me then check the first page you told me to check and search for 'C# that uses Dictionary field'

Comment: Nah that was because I ran an exploit to test it and it was just like this. before putting your log work it wasn't sending any messages at all and now it sends like its hasn't improved yet from the old ver of the program

Comment: ok, I checked the page and searched for the "C# that uses". What do I see there? "return _d[2];" - exactly the same code that I've typed before. OMG...

Comment: Don't use ContainsValue! you don't need it!

Comment: @Skipper and one more update for you. Do you understand everything in the Upd4?

Comment: @Skipper try it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XEhhst it works, and it does what you want.